# How to create pop up on selecting the checkbox in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table. Inside table i have rows, each with a column : checkbox.

as following

```
<table>
<tr class="row"> 
<td class ="checkclass" ><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row"> 
<td class ="checkclass" ><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want whenever i select the checkbox, a pop up is created.

Please note : i can not edit the html code.. However i can only do some changes in javascript.

PS : At last i want to highlight the selected row.

Comment: you could use the jquery .change() functionality

Comment: can u please answer. M new to javascript

Comment: and bootstrap for tooltip or modal for popup

Comment: Are you willing to use jquery?

Comment: @slash197 any simple pop up.. Simply by using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you could use the Jquery library and take advantage of the .change() functionality

```
$('.target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

reference: http://api.jquery.com/change/

On how to use JQuery is a different question

Now for javascript its a bigger hack:

```
function checkAddress(checkbox)
{
    if (checkbox.checked)
    {
        alert("a");
    }
}
```

To add the on click on the HTML with Javascript

```
document.getElementById("ElementID").setAttribute("onchange", function()   {checkAddress(this));
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkAddress" />
```

Comment: i dont have any id for checkbox

Comment: well you could do it with class name and apply it to all the checkboxes that have the same classname but you wont be able to put different script on different checkboxes

Comment: other choice is to get all the objects that share that classname and say child 1 should get that onchange event and child 2 should get that onchange event but for that please update your question

Answer (score 0):

please check following links

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

http://www.mywebdeveloperblog.com/my-jquery-plugins/modalpoplite

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class ="checkclass" ><input type="checkbox" onchange='checkBoxClicked();'></td>


  function checkBoxClicked()() {
     alert("Hi");
  }

for more info you can use [javascript pop-up][1] but i will suggest to go with jQuery or modal 


  [1]: http://www.echoecho.com/jsbasics.htm
```

Comment: i cant include onchange or anything in the html

Comment: do you have any js library included in page?

Comment: yes i do have jquery, backgrid, backbone, underscore liberaries

Answer (score 0):

you can do with jquery

```
$('.checkclass input').change(function() {
  // code here
});
```

I hope it will help to solve your problem.